# Some links (to resources) don't have a protocol

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow

Some links to resources on Stack overflow do miss the protocol in the links, f.e. `//ajax.google.com/...` when it should be `http://ajax.google.com/...`.

[image]

Comment: Why do protocols need to be there? Those will simply use the same protocol the page was loaded on. Those are valid, relative links. I'm always a little surprised those aren't used more.

Comment: Those are protocol-relative URLs, see [Types of URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743247/types-of-urls).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are protocol relative URLs. Such URLs will enable a seamless transition to the HTTPS protocol some day...

Comment: Worth to mention [this Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4831741/447356) in this context for those who doubt how reliable this is.